# Problema com o include

Tags: php, mvc, include

Então, estou com problemas na hora de realizar o include. Já realizei várias vezes este mesmo método de endereçar o arquivo que está na pasta controller, mas agora não está funcionando. O que pode ser?

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/controleEstoque/controller/MaterialController.class.php";
$cMaterial = new MaterialController();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema resolvido. O problema é qu estava iniciando a tag apenas com o

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual. Pedidos de mero debug de código pronto, tutoriais e/ou coisas que envolvem mais de um assunto no mesmo post geralmente não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tem dúvida em algum detalhe específico, reduzir o código a um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante. Fundamental não postar texto como imagem.

Comment: Ok, sem problema. Foi realizado testes, não encontrei a resposta. Sou novo por aqui, então estou aprendendo, mas obrigado. :)

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou usar o caminho relativo? Talvez funcione:

`.` = diretório atual

`..` = diretório anterior

`/` = raiz (sistemas `*nix`)

`~` = home (também em `*nix`)

Ou use o `dirname()`.

ex:

```
require_once "{dirname(__FILE__)}/CaminhoRelativoDoArquivo.php";
require_once "{dirname(__FILE__)}/../ExemploArquivoDiretorioSuperior.php";
require_once "{dirname(__FILE__)}/../test/ExemploArquivoDiretorioVizinho.php";
require_once "{dirname(__FILE__)}/ExemploArquivoMesmoDiretorio.php";
```

Comment: Então, mesmo realizando essas formas de chegar no arquivo, não dá certo. Ele reconhece que o arquivo existe, consigo chegar nele através do windows explorer, mas não encontra a classe.

Comment: Já tentou usar um autoload? Aí, ao invés de dar os includes, você só diz o que cada classe usa. Dá até pra usar duas classes diferentes com o nome igual no mesmo arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

A dica é antes do include vc verificar se o arquivo existe.

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/controleEstoque/controller/MaterialController.class.php";
if(file_exists($file)){
    include $file;
}
```

Você também pode verificar qual endereço está pegando, fazendo assim:

```
echo $file;
```

Em seguida corrigir o caminho, como for necessário.

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro. Gostei dessa ideia de fazer a verificação, nunca havia feito, mas mesmo assim, não funciona. O caminho está correto, quando digito, o caminho printado, no windows explorer ele abre o arquivo.

Comment: Nesse caso, pode ter algo errado com a criação da sua classe.
Têm como incluir as primeiras linha do arquivo "MaterialController.class.php" ??